# When media player is in paused state, why it gains focus onAudioFocusChange?

Tags: java, android

I noticed it last night during phone call. My app contains an online media player which resumes and pause itself `onAudioFocusChange`.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                // Resume your media player here
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                // Pause your media player here
                break;
        }
    }
```

But when it is already paused and the call comes , after cutting the call it starts again with the status still showing pause state.

Here is my toogle button which cause the media player to pause or play.

```
private void togglePlayPause() {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            nowplaying.setText("Offline");
            mPlayerControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
       //call abandonaudiofocus here     

        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            nowplaying.setText("Now Playing");
            mPlayerControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);

        }
    }
```

**Edit : Check my answer**

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK" case means that "when your App loose the Focus (DUCK meaning: in a special way that it can just reduce volume of its audio while another App is playing at normal volume) please check if the Player is in Pause and if Yes then start it".

So I suppose there is some other App that Requires AudioFocus using the DUCK variant and your Player resumes in that moment.

I suggest to move that Case in the same af all other "LOSS_..." or just to manage a "volume reduction action" when a DUCK action is detected by letting that Case live separately.

Comment: by doing this separately ; it is still behaving same .

Comment: can you give a snippet of how to check if player is in paused state or not

Comment: Maybe the issue occurs when your App receive the focus again after some other Apps (the Dial App?) has gained and then released its own focus. Please refer to official doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/audio-focus-3-cdc09da9c122). Posting it may helps someone.
We have to call

```
mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
```

when user initiates pause method.
This may not cause your app to regain focus when it is in paused state. And happily it solves my problem in this use case :')